# Mouse has the reverse orientation from screen

Tags: command-line, mouse, bug-reporting, system-settings

So, my laptop always begins upside down, even If I locked it before I shut it down. This wouldn't be much of a problem if the mouse didn't have the opposite orientation of the screen. If the screen is upwards, the mouse is downwards, and things like that. Does anyone know how to fix this?
This is the first time I'm trying Ubuntu, sorry if it's a dumb question. Thank you for your help!